# How to convert DD:HH:MM to HH:MM in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I am facing a problem with excel.How can I convert DD:HH:MM to HH:MM in excel?

Here is an exmaple showcasing what I need.
 1:02:49(1day, 2hours, 49 mins) should come as 26:49(26 hours, 49 min)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your `1:02:49` cell is formatted as text; otherwise, you could just change the cell format from DD:HH:MM to HH:MM.

I've opted to output as text, but could change it to an actual Time value if needbe.

Yes, the formula is a bit long but it can cope with any number of digits between each `:`. So, for example, `100:3:4` (100 days, 3 hours, 4 minutes) would correctly evaluate to `2403:04`

```
=24*LEFT(A1,FIND(":",A1)-1)+MID(A1,FIND(":",A1)+1,LEN(A1)-2-LEN(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,":","@",2))))-LEN(LEFT(A1,FIND(":",A1)-1)))&":"&TEXT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,":","@",2))),"00")
```